# Gravity Forms radio buttons overlapping with text

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm currently creating a form with Gravity Forms on a Wordpress site ([lightspeedinternet.com.au/residential/signup](http://lightspeedinternet.com.au/residential/signup/)), however I'm finding the text label is overlapping with the radio button. Trying to edit the CSS of the label moves the radio button as well?
Any tips on how to fix this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this custom style to your css:

```
#label_2_2_0 {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

this will add a left padding for your label

Comment: thank you this worked! Is there a way to do this to all the labels in one go, otherwise I have to do each label id one by one (.label doesn't work for me)

Comment: @alexbowersau sure, just use `.gfield_radio label {padding-left: 30px !important;}` this will target the labels for the radio buttons